# angular2 input value bind from another input with ngmodel directive

Tags: angular

Consider i have two inputs like the below

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value1" type="number">
<input [(ngModel)]="value2" type="number">
```

the value2 should be updated when i  type any number in value1.

I tried something like below

```
<input [ngModel]="value1" (ngModelChange)="value2=value1*value2" type="number">
<input [(ngModel)]="value2" type="number">
```

but the [value2=value1*value2] updates the value1 with the value2 data

Answer (score 1):

Try `change` event instead of `ngModelChange` as below :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value1" (change)="value2=value1*value2" type="number">
<input [(ngModel)]="value2" type="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ng-change event :

```
<input ngModel="value1" ng-change="value2=value1*value2" type="number">
<input ngModel="value2" type="number">
```